# Getting run time warning in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, notifications, push-notification

I am Creating xamarin iOS Application . and my project is based on Push Notification. For Registering the Push Notification i have write Following code-apping on it.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
// some code
            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationType = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (notificationType);
    // some code        
        }
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application,NSData deviceToken)
        {
//some code
}
public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application,NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Error AppDelegate push notification");
            new UIAlertView ("Error For Push Notification",error.LocalizedDescription,null,"OK",null).Show();
        }
        public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application,NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Recieve Notification calling ");
        }


        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {

            Console.WriteLine ("From DidReceiveRemoteNotification");
//              if([content-available]) {
//                  // fetch content
//                  completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
//              }
        }
```

so when i am running this application on device then i have not found the allow Push Notification Alert. and there is two warning .

```
warning MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 7.1 (11D167) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files.



error MT1007: Failed to launch the application 'com.laitkor.pilat' on the device 'Laitkor iPod': Look for earlier warnings returned: 0x454. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.
```

so i think these warning may be the reasons of push notification error. so please help me any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using an old Xcode (e.g. 5.0) and a device running iOS 7.1. That the warning your get, i.e. `MT1108`.

Such a configuration can work (most of the time) but will have a few drawbacks. E.g. the code that ships with Xcode cannot talk to the device (to start the application). That what's happening with the error, i.e. `MT1007`.

If you cannot update your Xcode (to 5.1) then you'll need to start your application manually (tapping on it's icon). Once it starts it should connect back to the debugger and you'll be back to normal.

Comment: so i think this should not be the reason of my push notification issue?because i am unable to receive the push notification.

Comment: Likely not - I do not see how it could affect push notifications. You might want to upgrade to Xcode5.1 anyway since it ease the debugging workflow.